# Is a copy constructor call guaranteed when passing argument by value

Tags: c++

Someone suggested to me that an optimizer is allowed to freely interchange parameter-passing-by-const-reference and with parameter-passing-by-value in any function that does not modify the parameter. Is that allowed by the C++ standard?

Or stated differently, in the code

```
struct MyClass {
    MyClass(MyClass const& mc) { std::cout << "xxx" << std::endl; }
};

void foo(MyClass mc) { }

MyClass mc;
foo(mc);
```

does the C++ standard guarantee that "xxx" is always printed? (Reference to standard appreciated)

Comment: The compiler can generate any code it pleases that behaves as your code requires. It can't magically omit something such as printing your message, unless there's an explicit permission for this (and that only happens in one case, which is copy elision, and which doesn't apply to your situation).

Comment: Unless it is basic data-type or your function will probably modify the value inside, I would always pass by const ref as "default". This is just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the copy constructor will be used here. Copy elision is only allowed in certain circumstances, specified by C++11 12.8/31:

- in a `return` statement ...
- in a *throw-expression* ...
- when a temporary class object ... would be copied/moved ...
- when the *exception-declaration* of an exception handler declares an object of the same type ... as the exception object

None of these apply here, although the third would apply if you passed a temporary value:

```
foo(MyClass());
```

In this case the message might not be printed.

Furthermore, if the copy-constructor had no side effects, then the copy could be elided under the "as-if" rule in any case (whether or not the argument were a temporary) since doing so would not effect the program's visible behaviour.

Comment: Do you mean that in `foo(MyClass());` the compiler does not have to print the message? Then the if-clause in your last sentence would be misleading. At least, that is how I understand point 3.

Comment: @TobiasBrüll: Yes, if the argument is a temporary, then point 3 applies, so the message might not be printed. The last sentence would apply in any case, if there were no side effects (but not if there are, as in your example); sorry if you found it misleading, I'll try to find a better way of phrasing it.